# copying xml document excluding duplicate nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I just don't get how copying works in XSL... I have a document with some duplicate nodes and I would like to exclude them.

my document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd id="ab" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="ab" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="cd" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="cd" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="de" lang="en" version="2">
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

So it has a bunch of elements with the same id, version and lang. And all I want to do is copy the entire document but have each node only once...

How do I do that? Copy-of? Copy? for-each-group? A combination?

I'd like this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd  id="ab" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="cd" lang="en" version="1">
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd  id="de" lang="en" version="2">
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple grouping problem, here is an XSLT 3.0 solution (needs Saxon 9.6 PE or EE) using `for-each-group` and a composite key:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="cd" group-by="@id, @lang, @version" composite="yes">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[last()]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you could compute a single key with a concatenation of the three attribute values, separated by some separator character not occurring in the attribute values.

Comment: it's this xsl:copy... I don't really get how that works... So with xsl:copy I have to write xsl:copy and then inside it specifiy any changes I want applied on the copied nodes...?

Comment: `xsl:copy` makes a shallow copy of the `catalog` element, then the `xsl:for-each-group` with the  `xsl:copy-of` inside populates the  `catalog` with a deep copy of the last `cd` element found in each group.